# Excel 2010 chart does not show x axis value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Excel 2010, chart data series don't seem to show the X axis value. When you put your cursor on a certain data point, it shows "Series(Y axis value)"/ "Point(X axis value)"/ and "Value". The X axis value is text-type date series, eg 20010101, 20010102, 20010103.

Instead of showing this X axis value like "20010101", "20010102", it shows only the sequence of the X axis data- Point "1", Point "2", Point "3", and so on. When I check the source data, it shows correct X axis value in 'Horizontal Axis Labels'.

Charts in Excel 2003 didn't have this kind of issue. How can I solve this problem to show the proper X axis value?

Comment: Is it a scatter chart?

Comment: No it's column chart

Comment: SO is for programming questions. A question like this does not belong here, but on SuperUser.com instead.

Comment: Please add an example (e.g. screenshot).

Answer (score 3):

What range is specified for the X axis in the data source dialog?

If the data looks like numbers, and there is a label in the top left cell of the source data table, Excel will treat the first column like a data series, and not as X axis labels. Make sure that the top left cell (above the labels) is empty before creating the chart.

To fix an existing chart, open the Select Data dialog and adjust the source of the X axis labels.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on how to fix and existing chart? "What does adjust the source of the X axis labels" mean? What should I adjust them to?

Comment: @MatthewLock It means what it says. Edit the chart data and adjust the source of the X axis labels in the data source dialog. Exact steps depend on your Excel version. If that does not make sense to you, you may be looking at a different scenario. In that case you may want to ask your own question.

Comment: @teylyn I have tried method you mentioned, after reopen, problem remained. It's kind of random, some chart showing correctly, some not. If I keep reopen the file, at the end all chart gone with axis-x 1,2,3....

Comment: @EricK. you may want to start your own question about this, since it is not the same scenario as the original question.